# What am I? - My purposes are many

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I made a riddle.

> Should you wish to be unknown,
> I'll hide you from their eyes.
> Many who
> use me seek anonymity
> And therein my skill lies.
>
> Should you wish to portray fiction,
> I must be acquired,
> But only in
> the cases where
> My presence was there prior.
>
> Should you wish to be defended,
> from enemies you cannot see,
> my use is
> recommended
> though not everyone agrees.
>
> Though my purposes are many,
> the world knows me for a few.
> One was for
> a new plague
> And the other plagued the news.
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're

> a mask.

Should you wish to be unknown,
I'll hide you from their eyes.
Many who use me seek anonymity
And therein my skill lies.

> A mask can be used to hide your face, thus allowing you to be anonymous or not show yourself.

Should you wish to portray fiction,
I must be acquired,
But only in the cases where
My presence was there prior.

> When cosplaying a character, you'll often need to wear a mask (I couldn't find a plague doctor mask for my Percival de Rolo costume, though).

Should you wish to be defended,
from enemies you cannot see,
my use is recommended
though not everyone agrees.

> A mask helps filter germs such as viruses. Not everyone agrees to wear them.

Though my purposes are many,
the world knows me for a few.
One was for a new plague
And the other plagued the news.

> This refers to the COVID-19 pandemic and the use of masks to limit infection. The political right campaigned strongly against them, and it was often in the news.

Comment: Dammit, just as i was writing my answer. Well done though!